# Chernoff Bound for the above Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

the characteristic function of a Gaussian random variable X distributed as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is given by
 $\phi(w)=\exp(j\mu w-\frac{\mu^2 w^2}{2} )$

Please find the Chernoff Bound for the above Gaussian random variable.

Chernoff Bound is given by $P\{X>a\} \le \frac{\mathbb E[\exp(sX)]}{\exp(sa)}$ for $s>0$

I have no idea to think the solution of this question, can anyone help me?

Comment: The characteristic function is $\phi(w) = E(e^{iwX}).$ In the same way that it is calculated, you can calculate $E(e^{sX})$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, in fact, the mgf is calculated much easier (here finding chf by definition requires integration in the complex domain with some technicalities).